# How can import sql file to database and insert to table

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I'm trying import SQL file to Database and insert value to table 'config', **but after importing SQL table 'config' is null**

I tried without ajax it working but with ajax table is null.

Code:

```
$sql_dump = File::get(base_path('database/shop.sql'));

try {
    $dumptable = DB::connection('newshop')->getPdo()->exec($sql_dump);
    $insertdata = DB::connection('newshop')->table('config')->insert([
        'sitename' => 'test',
    ]);

    return 'success';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return 'error';
}
```

Comment: If you have access to `phpMyAdmin` use that

Comment: If you have access to MySQL Workbench use that. Or there are other tools as well if you have a quick search

Comment: I need dump sql :) I'm creating CMS

Comment: Then you rather use the mysql (or whatever RDBMS you use) command line client, as PDO does not support multi-queries.